# How does imports work in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I frankly have a hard time understanding how imports work in Swift. When I make a new class it will start out with:

```
import foundation
```

As an alternative we could use `import Swift` or `import UIKit` depending on what libraries we need. **BUT** I've noticed that if I simply remove the imports my projects runs without any problems (even though I use classes from these libraries). **This is where I need some help**: I'm wondering if that is because I have internal frameworks that I import Swift/UIKit/Foundation and thereby get the import. So imports works like plague... if they touch a new class everything that class touches will have access to that import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we found the issue. Someone had added header file to each framework with:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Removing this line made everything less mad.

Now about how imports works. If a class A in library A import library B, class A will not have access to UIKit even though library B imports UIKit. This is how I'd expect it to work and how it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when a class that you use imports that framework, **it is imported in your class too**. This is to make things more clear, for example when class `Foo`'s method `abc` has a parameter that needs `UIKit`, which is present in `Foundation`. Therefore, when you use the class `Foo`, `UIKit` is automatically imported.

As a side note, importing `UIKit` will import `Foundation`, in which it will also import `Darwin`. So it is really like plague. If a third party library (such as `Charts`) imports `UIKit`, it imports `Foundation` and `Darwin` too.

Comment: I also found another issue in our project. Someone on the team had added a header file to the swift libraries which stated: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>. Brilliant.

Comment: `Yes, when a class that you use imports that framework, it is imported in your class too.` - This is not working for me. I have a SwiftUI view which imports SwiftUI in a static library. In the App target, I have the App protocol and I'm importing the static library. Now, I shouldn't have any errors, since the library I'm Importing is already importing SwiftUI.. but I do have errors. When I import SwiftUI explicitly, it works.